# Changing certificate for live application and purchases

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a live app in the Xamarin UWP store and I have implemented the trial and a paid version which is working fine. Now I want to publish a new update of the app after I converted from PCL to.Net Standard 2.0. when I build, I get the certificate error and it asks me to enter the password for the certificate I uploaded to the server.

It doesn't accept my password. I am pretty sure that I enter a correct password. I don't know the reason. So my questions are;

1. Does certificate play any role in LicenseInformation? I am basically checking if it is trial or not with the code below. If I create a new certificate, will that cause any effect on existing purchases?
2. I tried with the new certificate using local CurrentAppSimulator, all works fine but although I re-associated to store app, I get exception using CurrentApp as below. Is it because of I am using different certificate than in the store? So if I provide a new submission with a new certificate, the problem will be solved?

> System.ExceptionException from HRESULT: 0x803F6107 Raw    at
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.get_LicenseInformation()

```
 #if !DEBUG
 licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
  #else
 licenseInformation = CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation;
  #endif
  licenseInformation.LicenseChanged +=LicenseInformation_LicenseChanged;
 if (licenseInformation.IsActive)
   {
  if (licenseInformation.IsTrial)
    {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to publish a new update of the app after I converted from PCL to .Net Standard 2.0.

If you switch to the latest .NET Standard 2.0, you'd better use the [Windows.Services.Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store) namespace relevant APIs instead. The [Windows.ApplicationModel.Store Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store) document has explained clearly.

> The Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace is no longer being updated with new features. If your project targets Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393) or a later release in Visual Studio (that is, you are targeting Windows 10, version 1607, or later), we recommend that you use the Windows.Services.Store namespace instead. For more information, see In-app purchases and trials. The Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace is not supported in Windows desktop applications that use the Desktop Bridge or in apps or games that use a development sandbox in Dev Center (for example, this is the case for any game that integrates with Xbox Live). These products must use the Windows.Services.Store namespace to implement in-app purchases and trials.

Comment: I have seen this but I thought that this is just a recommendation, not a must. because I am not really doing any in app purchases. this is just checking license information and redirecting the user to the store to buy full version if it is trial. If i dont need new features and desktrop bridge. it should be still fine according to the documentation

Comment: Beside that I cant figure out how can I use AppSimulator, windowsstoreproxy.xml in local to test the code

Comment: @batmaci There's no `AppSimulator` in `Windows.Services.Store` namespace. Please refer to [Implement trial functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#implement-trial) for more details.

Comment: so you cant test it before you publish an app to the store. Indeed this is same with Google play store but problem and difference is, if I publish Android App, i can republish immediately to the google play if anything goes wrong. Microsoft store is total pain, I published a new submission 2 days ago and it is still in process. I cant imagine to resubmit a new update right after testing IAP after going live. this is so painful and therefore Dev's are not willing to develop UWP.